# bibtex is not printing the list of cited items

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[showtrims, 10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=iso-alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{CS111.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Brookshear2019}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

my bib file contains the following:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}
@Book{Brookshear2019,
 title = {Computer Science: An Overview},
 publisher = {Pearson},
 year = {2019},
 author = {J. Glenn Brookshear and Dennis Brylow},
 editor = {PEARSON},
 OPTkey = {},
 OPTvolume = {},
 OPTnumber = {},
 OPTseries = {},
 OPTaddress = {},
 edition = {Global Edition},
 OPTmonth = {},
 OPTnote = {},
 OPTannote = {},
 url = {http://www.pearsonhighered.com/brookshear},
 urldate = {},
 OPTlastchecked = {},
 OPTdoi = {},
 isbn = {1292263423},
 OPTissn = {},
 OPTlocalfile = {},
 OPTabstract = {},
 OPTkeywords = {}
}

\end{thebibliography}
```

I am executing:

```
latex CS111-ES
biber CS111-ES
latex CS111-ES
latex CS111-ES
```

ok, `\cite{Brookshear2019}` is working well and produces something like: [BB19]
However, `\printbibliography` DOES NOT print anything

It was working ... but not anymore.
Probably some update is producing this issue?

Comment: Works for me. The `bib` file should just be a set of bib entries etc, no `\begin{thebibliography}{}`/`\end{thebibliography}`, but doesn't seem to cause an error.  Are there any errors/warnings in the `.log` or `.blg` file? Try clearing auxiliary files (`.aux`, `.bcf`, `.bbl` etc) and recompiling.

Comment: The title of your query mentions BibTeX, but your code shows that you use (or should be using) biber and biblatex. Please fix.

Comment: I fully agree with @DaiBowen that LaTeX code has no business being in a bib file; get rid of it.

Comment: Off-topic: The line `editor = {PEARSON},` is wrong. The argument of the `editor` field should be one or more persons, not the publisher.

Comment: The example works for me (the bibliography is on page 3 of the document, the citation shows on page 1). As has been pointed out the `\begin{thebibliography}{}`/`\end{thebibliography}` shouldn't be there, but it will just cause a warning and non further issues. Is this the exact code you ran over on your machine to see the issue? Usually if citations work alright the bibliography should also work. I can only think of artificial cases (which do not apply here) in which one would work, but not the other. So this is pretty mysterious.